# Python: Sort 2-Dimensional Array by Array length?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Sorry I have to ask, but I looked around for quite a while, finding nothing helpful.

Here's the problem; I have a list of Arrays:

```
list = [["I","Am"], ["An","Array", "Within", "An Array"]]
```

I want to sort "list" by the length of the Arrays it contains.

Sofar I've tried:

```
list.sort()

#and
def nc(x):
    return len(x)

list.sort(key=nc)
```

But these both return "None".
I would truly appreciate some help with this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a_list.sort()` results `a_list` to be sorted in place (modifying itself) and returns `None` as it is designed.

`sorted( a_list, key=len )` will return the sorted list.

BTW your input data is already sorted, what was the expected result?

Comment: Thank you Jokester! I kept using print(list.sort()... And I assumed it wasn't working, but in reality it was being sorted from shortest to longest array. Maybe I do need some sleep.

Answer (score 4):

The `.sort()` method sorts the list in-place.  Like most methods that mutate an object, it returns `None`, but if you look at the list you'll see that it *has* been sorted.  If you want to make a *copy* of the list that's sorted, then:

```
newlist = sorted(original_list, key=len)
```

will do it.  Note that your `nc` function, while correct, is more elaborate than needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_arrays = [["I","Am"], ["An","Array", "Within", "An Array"]]
list_output = []
index = 0 
for i in list_arrays:
    sorted_array = sorted(list_arrays[index])
    list_output.insert(index, sorted_array)
    index = index + 1
print list_output
```

this will give you the way out to sort the array of array

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
list = [["I","Am"], ["An","Array", "Within", "An Array"]]
print(sorted(list, key = lambda ele : len(ele), reverse = True))
```